# How to convert this Javascript code to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript code:

```
javascript: function iptxt() {
    var d = document;
    try {
        if (!d.body) throw (0);
        window.location = 'http://www.instapaper.com/text?u=' + encodeURIComponent(d.location.href);
    } catch (e) {
        alert('Please wait until the page has loaded.');
    }
}
iptxt();
void(0)
```

I'll use it like this:

```
< href="javascript:function iptxt(){var d=document;try{if(!d.body)throw(0);window.location='http://www.instapaper.com/text?u='+encodeURIComponent(d.location.href);}catch(e){alert('Please wait until the page has loaded.');}}iptxt();void(0)">Go</a>
```

But I want to use this code with jquery, like this:

```
<a href="#" id="go">Go</a>
```

and what will be the jquery code that will integrate with the id go.

Thanks.

Comment: jquery is javascript, so you're already done!

Comment: @Boundless You should read more than just the title of the question.

Comment: @Amberlamps I'm not sure I should have answered. It seems to me like the most helpful behavior but I'm still unsure. Comments welcome, if possible on javascript chat.

Comment: @dystroy: This is a free world. Do as you like. I am happy to help anybody, but I am not a google search engine. This is the most basic jQuery task.

Comment: @Amberlamps What does "No effort, not help!" mean to someone who isn't an active stackoverflow user?  What is trivial to you is often completely unfamiliar to others.  I'm not saying do their work for them but at least be more informative about the general practices of the site and help them get on the right track...

Comment: @rudolph9: You might be corret there, but why didn´t you do that just now?

Comment: @Amberlamps By the time I saw the question, he already has two answers and large string of comments debating this... But to anyone who doesn't know what were talking about, you want to make sure you have sufficiently searched for an answer to your question before posting and make sure you post what you have tried and what you are confused about.  Last "thank you notes don't go in the questions them selves.  Either put them in comments, preferably just up vote good answers and accept the best one.

Comment: @Yoshi Agreed SO is not the place, but my point was it promotes a better stackoverflow if we help newcomers understand what's going on rather than just telling them they are wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just put the function call in a callack given to [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) :

```
<script>
$(function(){
    function iptxt(){
       var d=document;
       try{
         if(!d.body)throw(0);window.location='http://www.instapaper.com/text?u='+encodeURIComponent(d.location.href);
       } catch(e){alert('Please wait until the page has loaded.');}
    }

    $('#go').click(iptxt);
});
</script>
```

But this is the most basic jQuery task. Please have a look at [jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).

Comment: @udb Make sure you accept the answer which best answers your question (if any actually do...).

Comment: @rudolph9, yea i've marked!

Comment: @udb Awesome! I'm glad you got your question answered.  If you ever have questions about how something works on StackOverflow just checkout/post on the [MetaStackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    var d = document;
    try{
        if(!d.body){
            window.location = 'http://www.instapaper.com/text?u=' + encodeURIComponent(d.location.href);
        }
    }
    catch(e){
        alert('Please wait until the page has loaded.')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure why you do the `if(!d.body)throw(0);` does not make much sens to me.
but this is how to do in jQuery.

```
$("#go").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var d=document;
     try{
          if(!d.body)throw(0);
          window.location='http://www.instapaper.com/text?u='+encodeURIComponent(d.location.href);
     }catch(e){
          alert('Please wait until the page has loaded.');
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please simplify this code for me.. I just need the result:
http://www.instapaper.com/text?u='+encodeURIComponent'

Comment: at the time a click event can be done the body of the document already exists. do i don't know why you check for the existing of the body with this statement `if(!d.body)throw(0);`

Comment: actually i dont know javascript..
you mean i can remove <code>if(!d.body)throw(0);</code> and replace it with only if?